# How can i define a fix speed of velocity in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, vector, velocity

I've code a program with bouncing balls.

Here I make the ball and I define the point where the ball will fly:

```
X = ((X - event.pageY) / 25) * -1;
Y = ((Y - event.pageX) / 25) * -1;

function newBallMaker()
{
    var start = new Point(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight);
    var ball = new Ball();
    ball.position = end;
    ball.velocity = new Vector(X,Y); 
    ball.move();
    balls.push(ball);
    ballCounter++;
}

this.position.x += this.velocity.x1;
this.position.y += this.velocity.x2;
```

But I have a problem, I can't define the speed of the ball. If I click in the middle of the bottom, the ball will be very slow, but if I click in the left of the top the ball will be very fast.

How can I define a fix speed of the ball?

Comment: There is no enough information for your question. And that's some kind of control inside `move` method of `Ball` if you write it yourself